# Excel VBA to copy cells from one worksheet to another based on adjacent cells

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I asked in a previous thread how to copy cells from one worksheet to another based on cell value (e.g. if cell A3 has an 'x', copy the value from cell B3 on to worksheet "work").

I was successful in writing some VBA code to perform the task, but it will end up being extremely long (I have 30 worksheets to scan).

Here is what works (right now it is set to only do 2 worksheets)

```
Private Sub Load_Order_Click()
' Setup Data
    Dim Last_Row0 As Long
    Dim ws0 As Worksheet
    Set ws0 = Sheets("work")

' Sort and Copy Data from each page to Work
' Sheet 1
With Sheets("1 - Conduit")
    .Range("A:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="x"
    .Range("a2", .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Copy
    End With
With Sheets("work")
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
' Sheet 2
With Sheets("2 - Elbows")
    .Range("A:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="x"
    .Range("a2", .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Copy
    End With
With Sheets("work")
    Last_Row0 = ws0.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Range("A" & Last_Row0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With

' Not Sure
' Sheet 1
With Sheets("1 - Conduit")
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:C").AutoFilter
    End With
' Sheet 2
With Sheets("2 - Elbows")
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:C").AutoFilter
    End With
End Sub
```

I would prefer to do this in a "While" or "For" Loop.  I think I have it correct, but when I run it, it does not perform.  Here is what I have written, and then I will comment what I think my issues are.

```
Private Sub Load_Order_Click()
' Setup Data
    Dim Last_Row0 As Long
    Dim ws0 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer           ' Copy loop
    Dim x As Integer           ' "Not Sure" loop
    Dim max As Integer         ' Maximum number of pages Adjustment
    Dim pages As Integer       ' Number of Worksheets to copy through

    Set ws0 = Sheets("work")
    Set pages = 30
    Set max = pages + 1

' Sort and Copy Data from each page to Work - Loop Function
For i = 1 to max
    If i = 1 Then
        Sheets("1 - Conduit").Activate
        .Range("A:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="x"
        .Range("a2", .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Copy
        Sheets("work").Activate
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Else
        Sheets("1 - Conduit").Activate
        Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index + (i - 1)).Select
        .Range("A:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="x"
        .Range("a2", .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Copy
        Sheets("work").Activate
        Last_Row0 = ws0.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
Next i

' Not Sure
For x = 1 to max
    Sheets("1 - Conduit").Activate
    Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index + (i - 1)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:C").AutoFilter
Next x
End Sub
```

I think the code is correct.  Where I think my issue lies in how the original creator of the excel file made the worksheets.

Here is what I mean.  I need to check worksheets (these are the names of the worksheets on the tabs):  1 - Conduits; 2 - Elbows, 3 - *****; 4 - ******; 5 - ******; 6 - ****** (you get the idea).  However, when I look in the VBA code window, the worksheets are numbered as follows:

Sheet1 = 4 - *****; Sheet2 = 7 - *****; Sheet3 = 1 - *****; Sheet4 = 2 - *****; Sheet5 = Order (not a sheet to be scanned)

And I believe I am indexing against "Sheet#" when I step through, and since the sheets I need to check are all screwed up in sequence, I get to a point that the code just gives up.

So my questions are this:

1. Is my code correct?  Or did I get something wrong?
2. Is my hypothesis correct, and I need to create a brand new excel workbook    and make certain that the first 4 worksheets are the worksheets not to be scanned and then index off Sheet5?

Answer (score 0):

I have pointed out several mistakes in your code. Here, you may see the updated version of your code with my comments. I have checked with the debugger in the vba console and it worked without error. But, I am not sure whether it will work with your data or not.

```
Private Sub Load_Order_Click()
' Setup Data
    Dim Last_Row0 As Long
    Dim ws0 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer           ' Copy loop
    Dim x As Integer           ' "Not Sure" loop
    Dim max As Integer         ' Maximum number of pages Adjustment
    Dim pages As Integer       ' Number of Worksheets to copy through

    Set ws0 = Sheets("work")
    '======================================
    'you don't need to set an integer;
    'just assign a value as below
    '======================================
    pages = 30
    max = pages + 1

' Sort and Copy Data from each page to Work - Loop Function
For i = 1 To max
    If i = 1 Then
        Sheets("1 - Conduit").Activate
        '======================================
        ' You have to begin with activesheet like below
        '======================================
        With ActiveSheet
        .Range("A:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="x"
        .Range("a2", .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Copy
        Sheets("work").Activate
        'here is another confusing line
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With

    Else
        Sheets("1 - Conduit").Activate
        Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index + (i - 1)).Select
        '======================================
        ' same here
        '======================================
        With ActiveSheet
        .Range("A:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="x"
        .Range("a2", .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Copy
        Sheets("work").Activate
        Last_Row0 = ws0.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With
    End If
Next i

' Not Sure
For x = 1 To max
    Sheets("1 - Conduit").Activate
    Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index + (i - 1)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:C").AutoFilter
Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: So I wasn't too far off, but still not correct.  Thank you.  You did comment:

   [ 'here is another confusing line
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues ]

is a confusing line.  My intention is to copy range A2:{last data} from the active sheet (e.g. 1 - Conduits) and paste just the values on a separate worksheet named "work" starting at cell A1.  I found this code searching various topics on this site and other VBA tutorials.  I hope this helps explain the meaning of this line.

Comment: Do you have any insight to my 2nd question in the post?  Is my hypothesis correct and I will need to create a whole new workbook to ensure the order of the worksheets to be scanned are in the proper order?

Comment: I am not sure about your second question. In my experience, worksheet index number and Worksheet names are not always in a certain order. So, looping through worksheets may result in somehing that you don't want.